# Extract text from Webpages with Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working with Python 3.x

I want to extract text from several webpages. What is a good library to allow me do just that?

Thanks,
Barry.

Comment: Depending on what you're aiming at, you could use module **re**. 95 % people are frowning upon such an advice, but the fact is that I do extract texts from web pages with **re** and with plenty of satisfactory, without all the horrid things they are warning upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

and the documentation to get you started

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

Comment: I hear that lxml is faster than BeautifulSoup, but either one should still work.

Comment: @John Doe According to a test I did one time, _lxml_ is 10 times slower than BeatifulSoup, and the latter 10 times slower than module **re**. This comparison should be verified, but anyway I'm convinced that if the ratios are not 10, they're at least 2.

Answer (score 1):

`mechanize` is good library but unfortunately not ready for python 3, but you can take a look at [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20HTML) and than it's just a matter of going through the returned structure for anything similar to an email address.

You could also just use urllib2 for this but Beautiful Soup takes care of a lot of syntax issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you want to *do* with the extracted text, and that makes a *big* difference in how much effort you are willing to go to in order to get it out.

If you are trying to get the *body text* of a web page minus all of the site-related cruft (a *nontrivial* task), take a look at [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). It is written in Java, but it does an amazingly good job at getting essential text out of random web pages.

One of my hobbies over the next few weeks is recreating the core logic of boilerpipe in Python. We need the functionality it provides for a project, but don't want to haul the 10-ton rock that is the JVM around with it. I'm pretty certain we will be releasing it once it is fairly stable.